# Why does m_array.count fail when used as the conditional in a for loop?

Tags: objective-c

This works:

```
int i, start, end;

start = m_cardArr.count - 1;
end = m_cardArr.count - 4;
NSLog(@"%i %i", m_cardArr.count - 1, m_cardArr.count - 4);
for(i = start; i > end; i--)
{
    LabyrinthCard* labyCard = (LabyrinthCard*)[m_cardArr objectAtIndex:i];
    if(labyCard.m_type != cardType || labyCard.m_usedForDoor)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This doesn't enter the for loop at all:

```
int i;

NSLog(@"%i %i", m_cardArr.count - 1, m_cardArr.count - 4);
for(i = m_cardArr.count - 1; i > m_cardArr.count - 4; i--)
{
    LabyrinthCard* labyCard = (LabyrinthCard*)[m_cardArr objectAtIndex:i];
    if(labyCard.m_type != cardType || labyCard.m_usedForDoor)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I am not changing the size of the array inside, so using m_cardArr.count as the conditional should work. In both cases, the NSLog prints 2, -1 when there are 3 elements in the array.

I can't figure out what I'm missing here.

Comment: I searched pretty hard for this, figuring it had already been answered. Sorry I didn't manage to find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because the `count` property is of type `NSUInteger`, i.e. an unsigned number. When you subtract `4` from it and the result becomes negative, it gets interpreted as a very large positive number.

When you assign that result to an `int`, you re-interpret it as a negative again, fixing the problem.

The best way of addressing this would be moving `-4` to the other side of the expression, changing the sign to a `+`, like this:

```
for(i = m_cardArr.count - 1; i+4 > m_cardArr.count; i--) {
    ...
}
```

The logic behind the expression would remain the same, but you would no longer see the signed/unsigned side effects caused by subtraction.

Comment: Woa... I thought it was something weird like this. Thanks!